# Подробнее о сборщике мусора в Java.

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане!
На сегодняшней лекции по ООП преподаватель начал подавать нам азы Java (ранее был прочитан курс лекций по C/C++).

В общем, есть возможность выступить перед потоком, дабы зарекомендовать себя перед грядущей сессией и получить автомат. Предполагаемая тема: Сборщик мусора.

Хочу, чтобы Вы мне помогли с поиском нужной информации. Я не прошу ссылок на готовенькие презентации и что-то в этом роде. Хотелось бы просто, чтобы Вы мне указали парочку учебников, интернет-источников, возможно, где было бы грамотно и, что важнее для меня сейчас (я, как большинство людей из потока, пока не знаком с Java), понятно описан метод работы Сборщика мусора.

Надеюсь, что Вы меня поймете. Заранее Всем спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая же ссылка по запросу Google "алгоритм сборки мусора" ведет сюда: [cборка мусора](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0). IMHO вполне достойный для начала материал. По второй ссылке - [Теория и практика Java: Сборка мусора в HotSpot JVM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp11253/) - находим конкретный материал для Java.

Answer (score 1):

"Не прошу ссылок", но "хотелось бы парочку интернет-источников" .. это как?=))
Читай [Брюса Эккеля](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8E%D1%81+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Там хорошо написано как работает сборщик мусора и вообще обо многом из java

Comment: Автор не хочет ссылок на **готовые презентации**.

Comment: avp, да, именно так ставил "логическое ударение" =) Спасибо за это и за ответ ниже :D. 

Виталий Кустов, спасибо за автора! =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, будьте менее экспрессивны в своих выражениях.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка на готовую видео презентацию на английском [Understanding Java Garbage Collection](https://youtu.be/we_enrM7TSY) (может кому-то ещё будет интересно).

Comment: Лучше основную информацию выносить в сам ответ. Ссылки бьются, и ответ становится бесполезным.